# Complicated Expression Java

Tags: java

```
 public class I {
        public static void main(String  args[])
        {
            int i=0,j=1,k=2;
            i=i++ - --j + ++k;
            System.out.println("\ni : "+i+"\nj : "+j+"\nk : "+k);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please explain to me Why the above code gives output :

```
i : 3
j : 0
k : 3
```

Instead of giving the output :

```
i : 4
j : 0
k : 3
```

?

Comment: Got it... Thank you all for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. i++ - gives 0 (and increments i)
2. --j decrements and gives 0
3. ++k increments and gives 3
4. the result of 0 + 0 + 3 is assigned to i (which overwrites i's value 1).

Therefore: i : 3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your confusion hinges on the use of `i++` - but the side effect of `i++` incrementing `i` has no effect, since `i` is reassigned the result of the "complicated expression".

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the line in question produces, Remember that if `i` is 0, then `i++ == 0` and `++i == 1`

```
i = i++ - --j + ++k;
i = (0) - (-0) + (3) // i is 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the difference between post increment and pre increment operators.

Pre increment comes before the variable (e.g. `++i`) and post increment comes after the variable (e.g. `i++`).

Break it down into smaller parts:

```
i++   // post increment means increment AFTER we evaluate it
      // expression evaluates to 0, then increment i by 1

--j   // pre decrement means decrement BEFORE evaluation
      // j becomes 0, expression evaluates to 0

++k   // pre increment means increment BEFORE evaluation
      // k becomes 3, expression evaluates to 3
```

So now we have:

```
i = 0 - 0 + 3   // even though i was set to 1, we reassign it here, so it's now 3
```

Answer (score 1):

1. i++ gives 0 and then i becomes 1
2. --j makes j become 0 and then gives 0, plus 0 from step 1 gives 0
3. ++k makes k become 3 and then gives 3, plus 0 from step 2 gives 3, which is stored into i

Hence, i is 3, j is 0 and k is 3.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `i` is `3` because the expression is evaluated like that:

```
 i++ //still equals 0 since it's incremented after the evaluation
 -
 --j // equals 0 too since it's decremented is done before the evaluation
 +
 ++k // equals 3 since it's incremented before the evaluation
```